# Defining TokensRegex for Stanford NLP RegexNER

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to create a regex token to tag Universities as schools in input text. For e.g. University of Wisconsin or Universidad Anahuac should get tagged as SCHOOL.
I have this as my pattern

```
( /University|Universidad/ /of?/ [ {ner:LOCATION}|{ner:ORGANIZATION} ]+ )   SCHOOL
```

I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Any help would be appreciated.